# JSONDecodeError in json.load() with everything seeming right

Tags: python, json

So I got the JSONDecodeError in json.load() while everything seems to be right.
My code:

```
def write(name: str, text):
    try:
        with open("C:/Users/FlexGames/Desktop/Programming/Discord Bot/New Bot/banned.json", "w") as bannedload:
            bannedjson[name] = text
            json.dump(bannedjson, bannedload)

    except NameError:
        _load(jsonfile)
        return write(name, text, jsonfile) 
   
def _load():
    global bannedjson, bannedload
    with open("C:/Users/FlexGames/Desktop/Programming/Discord Bot/New Bot/banned.json", "r") as bannedload:
        bannedjson = json.load(bannedload)
```

JSON File:

```
{
    "banned": []
}
```

Error Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Try Me Btch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FlexGames\Desktop\Programming\Discord Bot\New Bot\main.py", line 77, in on_message
    await ban.user(message)
  File "C:\Users\FlexGames\Desktop\Programming\Discord Bot\New Bot\New_Functions\ban.py", line 11, in user
    jsonhandle.write("banned", int(content[1]))
  File "C:\Users\FlexGames\Desktop\Programming\Discord Bot\New Bot\Functions\jsonhandle.py", line 27, in write
    _load(jsonfile)
  File "C:\Users\FlexGames\Desktop\Programming\Discord Bot\New Bot\Functions\jsonhandle.py", line 42, in _load
    bannedjson = json.load(bannedload)
  File "C:\Users\Try Me Btch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\Try Me Btch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Try Me Btch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Try Me Btch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Most "solutions" I found in the internet were faults like .loads() or large and lower case faults or something like this but not this error in this context

Comment: We would need the json content to verify nothing is wrong there...

Comment: @Capie added the JSON File content

Comment: That json loads just fine for me, I reckon you've got something screwy going on with the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was like SiHa said something was broken with the path, I don't know what exactly but as I removed the whole path but the file it worked ‍♂️